# Routing traffic through OpenVPN on Kubernetes with Calico

Tags: networking, kubernetes

I am running a kubernetes cluster on the IBM container service.

I have an OpenVPN pod set up, which successfully allows clients to connect. Clients have fixed IPs assigned using CCD (in the range `10.240.0.0/16`).

I would like other pods in my cluster (in `172.30.42.0/24`) to be able to access clients connected via OpenVPN.

I have attempted to implement this by adding a route to the host node:

`ip route add 10.240.0.0/16 via 172.30.42.65` (where `172.30.42.65` is the OpenVPN pod)

This, briefly, allows traffic from other pods on the node to route traffic to OpenVPN clients. Unfortunately, Calico's Felix removes the root after a short period.

Is it possible to set up a route from nodes to VPN clients via the VPN server pod, accepting that Calico appears to be enforced by IBM?

I've seen https://github.com/pieterlange/kube-openvpn, which achieves something close using port forwarding. This, however, is dependent on setting up a port forward rule for every VPN client, which I'd rather avoid (it feels like we're re-inventing routing with this solution...)

I'd assumed that this would be achievable with Calico config, but I can't find anything that appears to do the right thing in their documentation.

Answer (score 1):

[Calico has an annotation](https://docs.projectcalico.org/v2.5/reference/cni-plugin/configuration) where you can specifying the IP address for Pod:

```
annotations:
        "cni.projectcalico.org/ipAddrs": "[\"192.168.0.1\"]"
```

You can specify address for your OpenVPN pod in the annotation and then create the static rout for OpenVPN clients.

Comment: This is useful to know, but Felix still removes any static routes added to the host.