# Connects to OpenVPN but no access to local network or internet in Kubernetes GKE with Calico

Tags: networking, openvpn, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, calico

I've been using VPN (openvpn in helm) to access internal services in my cluster for development.
I enabled `network policy in nodes` in GKE to manage access of services, that enabled Calico network in my network, after this my openvpn connection stopped working, I can connect to it, but can't access internet or LAN.

---

I've used default config:
https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/openvpn/values.yaml

here is iptables-saves output:

```
➜  cat iptables-save_output_on_one_of_k8s_node.txt | grep stagingvpn
-A KUBE-FW-W5MFW2XRXQ2S2XVL -m comment --comment "develop/stagingvpn-openvpn:openvpn loadbalancer IP" -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-FW-W5MFW2XRXQ2S2XVL -m comment --comment "develop/stagingvpn-openvpn:openvpn loadbalancer IP" -j KUBE-SVC-W5MFW2XRXQ2S2XVL
-A KUBE-FW-W5MFW2XRXQ2S2XVL -m comment --comment "develop/stagingvpn-openvpn:openvpn loadbalancer IP" -j KUBE-MARK-DROP
-A KUBE-NODEPORTS -p tcp -m comment --comment "develop/stagingvpn-openvpn:openvpn" -m tcp --dport 32093 -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-NODEPORTS -p tcp -m comment --comment "develop/stagingvpn-openvpn:openvpn" -m tcp --dport 32093 -j KUBE-SVC-W5MFW2XRXQ2S2XVL
-A KUBE-SEP-APWPTBIASIKM3IVR -s 10.12.3.16/32 -m comment --comment "develop/stagingvpn-openvpn:openvpn" -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-APWPTBIASIKM3IVR -p tcp -m comment --comment "develop/stagingvpn-openvpn:openvpn" -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 10.12.3.16:443
-A KUBE-SERVICES ! -s 10.12.0.0/14 -d 10.15.247.123/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "develop/stagingvpn-openvpn:openvpn cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 443 -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.15.247.123/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "develop/stagingvpn-openvpn:openvpn cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 443 -j KUBE-SVC-W5MFW2XRXQ2S2XVL
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d MYPUBLICIP/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "develop/stagingvpn-openvpn:openvpn loadbalancer IP" -m tcp --dport 443 -j KUBE-FW-W5MFW2XRXQ2S2XVL
-A KUBE-SVC-W5MFW2XRXQ2S2XVL -m comment --comment "develop/stagingvpn-openvpn:openvpn" -j KUBE-SEP-APWPTBIASIKM3IVR
```

---

How can I fix it?
I'm playing with ip ranges in configs, but no success, don't know what I should do next to debug my issue..
Any advices very welcome, much thx!!

---

What I tried already:
change `nodeport` in config from `32085` to `32093` - no luck
change `OVPN_NETWORK` and `OVPN_MASK` in config from to `10.12.3.16/32` - no luck

similar issue: https://github.com/helm/charts/issues/6398

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Routing traffic through OpenVPN on Kubernetes with Calico](https://serverfault.com/questions/911247/routing-traffic-through-openvpn-on-kubernetes-with-calico)

Comment: Any success @animekum??

Comment: @blackjid no :CC calico core developer said that it's because of calico blocks ip spoofing in openvpn, but I didn't find any workaround, he said to use node host network if I want to use vpn, but don't know how to vpn into cluster network now :(

Comment: I just solved a similar problem, but for me, the problem wasn't Calico. The symptoms in my cluster where the same. I had network policies w/calico enabled and I was able to connect to the vpn, but no traffic was routed to the cluster except for the openvpn own pod ip address.

Comment: Did you tried setting up  `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` in the openvpn container. ?